# Property 'params' does not exist on type 'StackProps<"Detail">'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-navigation, react-typescript

I am getting error while trying to retrive data from `route.params` It gives error saying this.
What should be type of `route`.

> Property 'params' does not exist on type 'StackProps<"Detail">'

Although i have defined type for `route` but it still giving me error. This is my code

> RouteParamList.tsx

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
export type RouteParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Detail: { productId: number };
};
export type StackProps<T extends keyof RouteParamList> = {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<RouteParamList, T>;
  route: RouteProp<RouteParamList, T>;
};
```

> DetailScreen.tsx

```
interface DetailScreenProps {
  route: StackProps<"Detail">;
  
}
export function DetailScreen({ route }: DetailScreenProps) {
  
  const { productId }: { productId: number } = route.params; <-- I am getting error here
  const dataDisplay = data.find((el, index) => {
    if (el.id !== productId) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return el.id === productId;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the way interfaces are set up at the moment, you need to access `route.route.params`. note that `DetailScreenProps.route` is of type `StackProps<"Detail">` which also has a property `route`.

instead of using `route.route.params` you could also think about changing the interface like that:

```
interface DetailScreenProps extends StackProps<"Detail"> { }
```